# Excel in userform textbox using VBA

Tags: vba

I want the value of textbox2 be populated on exit from textbox1 above but VBA code is not working.

```
Private Sub textbox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    textbox1.Value = Format(textbox1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    textbox2.Value.Formula = "=Right(if(month(textbox1.value)>3,Year(textbox1.value)+1,Year(textbox1.value)),2)" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Need editing for readability

Answer (score -1):

Neither textbox object nor its `.Value` property have a `Formula` member, like `range` object has.

So you have to make calculations directly in the code.

Try this

```
Private Sub textbox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox1.value = Format(TextBox1.value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    TextBox2.value = Right(CStr(IIf(Month(TextBox1.value) > 3, Year(TextBox1.value) + 1, Year(TextBox1.value))), 2)
End Sub
```

You could also go:

```
Private Sub textbox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox1.value = Format(TextBox1.value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    TextBox2.value = IIf(Month(TextBox1.value) > 3, Year(TextBox1.value) + 1, Year(TextBox1.value))) mod 1000
End Sub
```

Comment: Your last 10 answers (and probably all of them) are written in lower-case, as if you are posting from a mobile phone. Might I trouble you to use the shift key occasionally? It does make things more readable `:-)`

Comment: Apparently so. [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293779/472495).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote ". your voting my answer should follow those rules. waiting for your explanation as to where my "post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate" and also why it's not "interesting, well-researched, and useful". otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed should apply. Peter Duniho didn't teach you anything?

Comment: You've not been around _Meta_ long enough: the general view of the community is that people may vote for any reason they like, as long as they don't serial-vote on one user. It seems that Peter is in agreement with that, in any case - his main point is that wilful stylistic errors should not be a moderation matter, since mods are hard-pressed as it is.

Comment: (I haven't voted on your posts more than once, so no, serial voting rules do not apply. You are learning the cost of a dismissive attitude - and that volunteer editors get annoyed at being given extra work).

Comment: your view is like that. mine is not as well as other people too. Peter wrote it down clearly and you should pay more attention at words than at their case. moderators should be pressed at such matters as users being annoyed by people like you. it'd be nice from you to give your opinion about the usefulness of my answer with regard to the OP's question.